# How to allocate memory for object of the derived class by pointer of the base class using malloc?

Tags: c++, inheritance, malloc, new-operator

For example there is a chain

```
class A
{
int a;
int b;
public:
A();
};

class B: public A
{
int c;
char b;
public:
B()
};
```

In ordinary way to create an object of the derived class we can use this form

```
A* ptr = new B()
```

How to do the same using malloc ?

Comment: In your code, B is not derived from A.

Comment: Thanks, now it is fixed.

Comment: @ՎարդանԳրիգորյան Why are you using `malloc` instead of `new`?

Comment: I want to understand can we allocate memory and call ctor avoid using operator new?

Comment: @ՎարդանԳրիգորյան  Then please put that in your question, as it gives the impression you want to do things that lead to undefined behavior.  Using just `malloc` will not work for the classes you posted since they are not POD types:  http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/intrinsic-types#pod-types  What you are looking for is `placement-new` http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C-way of doing it:

```
A* ptr = (A*)malloc(sizeof(B));
*(B*)ptr = B();
```

---

The C++-way of doing it:

```
A* ptr = static_cast<A*>(malloc(sizeof(B)));
*static_cast<B*>(ptr) = B();
```

---

Note that since we're using C++, we have to cast the return-value of `malloc`.

Due to the "language mixture", there is no "ANSI way" to answer this question.

Comment: With the classes that the OP posted, how can this be used without invoking undefined behavior when attempting to use what was created?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Do you mean the `int b` and `char b` issue? I refrained from referring to that because it was not the main focus of the question. In fact, if you take a closer look at it, then you'll notice that this code wouldn't even compile due to a few other errors. But again, I preferred to address the main issue at hand, assuming that those were just typos in a piece of code that was written quickly (and carelessly) in order to illustrate that issue.

Comment: It's the user defined constructor `B()` and that `B()` has a parent class.  That makes it non-POD, thus using `malloc` to create such an object is viable only when using `placement new`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Your first statement is unclear to me. What about that constructor?

Comment: A class that has a user-defined constructor is non-POD.  A non-POD type cannot be just `malloc`ed for use.  You have to use `placement new` to use the actual object.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: This essentially makes the question impossible to answer, which is pretty much what I have implied at the bottom of my answer. I nevertheless tried to answer it given the "impossible" restriction of allocating a non-POD instance using `malloc`. Completing this with `new` as you suggested, would make the entire question pointless, so I don't see any better way to answer it (except, perhaps, adding an emphasis that the suggested solution yields UB according to the C++-language standard).

Comment: Questions can be wrong. The answer should be correct. Esp. if it is selected as the best answer. Inserting important information in comments is hardly the correct way to correct incorrect code. placement new is the correct thingy to use in C++ and if the questioner is barking up the wrong tree need to make it explicit that bad things are gonna happen. The last line ambigous "disclaimer" hardly does that job.

Comment: @GuruM: Please read the entire question before you down-vote the answer!!! OP asks to make use of `malloc`, which implicitly means the he or she wishes to avoid using `new` (for whatever reason). Given this sort of "impossible restriction", I explicitly stated that it cannot be answered perfectly. It is **not** an `ambiguous "disclaimer"` as you choose to call it, but rather a polite way of saying something like "that's the best you can do if you don't want to use `new`".

Answer (score 5):

Malloc returns a `void*` pointer to raw allocated memory. Just use a placement new operator on that memory.

```
void* mem = malloc( sizeof(B) );
A* ptr = new(mem) B(); // builds object in location pointed by mem
```

The placement new does not allocate memory, it just constructs your object in the given place.

Comment: But why you take sizeof(B)? When you want to allocate memory for int , then you can write like this int* ptr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)), it menas you take the type of ptr, which is int (avoiding pointer)

Comment: @ՎարդանԳրիգորյան If you want you can write `B* mem = malloc( sizeof(B) );`. It makes no difference in this case.

Comment: @ՎարդանԳրիգորյան But if you give `mem` type `B*`, you risk to forget the call to placement new, and try using that pointer directly, with bad results...

Answer (score 2):

`new` does a two step construction of an instance of a class. It allocates heap-memory and then calls the constructor of the class to initialize the object.

`operator new(size_t size)` in turn only deals with memory allocation and has a signature similar to `malloc()`. It does not call the constructor for the instance.

`operator new(size_t size, void* ptr)` is called placement new. It returns ptr after fully initializing the instance, calling the appropriate constructor.

If you need to use other types of memory than standard heap you can override operator new and placement new for your class. This comes in handy if you need to place the instance, say into thread local storage, shared memory or if you do some optimized data structures of sorts. Also, placement new is sometimes used in systems programming, placing the instance of the object on top of some register set with a known address in order to provide some abstraction of a hardware interface.

So, if you want/need to use malloc() for your instances, all you have to do is override operator new for your class. And possibly not forget to call a constructor.

```
#include <new>

A *ManuallyConstructBInstance()
{
    B *pB = reinterpret_cast<B*>(operator new(sizeof(B)));
    if( nullptr != pB )
    {
         new(pB) B(); // manual call of constructor using placement new.
    }
    return pB; // optionally use static_cast<A*>() if you want to emphasize the upcast.
}
```

The code sample above shows how it looks like if operator new() is used as a malloc() substitute, demonstrating that it only deals with raw memory and has no incling on class types etc.

To see how to overload operator new for your class, see for example
[here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/operator_new.html).

Comment: Please, can you give some short example how to call ctor after allocation of the memory, using base class pointer ?

Comment: `operator new(size_t size, void* ptr)` does not simply return `ptr`! It initializes your object, its virtual table, its default values...

Comment: @lodo right - it is a "full constructor" need to clarify that.